# Translation of a Label containing an url

Tags: twig, symfony-3.3

In my symfony3 project, I have a form field with label "I accept the cgu" with a link on the 'cgu'. 
How can I translate the label containing the link, as I must generate the link with `{{path('')}}` in twig ?

I tried something like that : 
`{{ form_row(form.valid, {'label' : 'annonces.form.valide_cgu_cgv' | trans ({'cgu_link' : {{ path('page_statique', {'page' : 'cgu'})}}, 'cgv_link' : {{ path('page_statique', {'page' : 'cgv'})}} }) |raw }) }}`
but it does not work...

Any idea ?

Thanks all !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are under `{{ }}`, you're writting an expression, so you can't put nested `{{ }}`.

You can try with:

```
{{ 
    form_row(form.valid, {
        'label' : 'annonces.form.valide_cgu_cgv' | trans({
            'cgu_link' : path('page_statique', {'page' : 'cgu'})
            'cgv_link': path('page_statique', {'page' : 'cgv'})
        })
    }) 
}}
```

Comment: Ok ! That works ! But The `| raw` does not work. I have my html visible in my page. Any idea ?

Comment: I had to override the `form_label` to add the `|raw`